# Cannot load kml

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I'm having trouble loading kml files on my prod server, localhost works fine.  I added the mime types to apache.  I use this code which works locally.  What could be causing this?

```
var link = ge.createLink('');
link.setHref(kml_url);
var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('');
networkLink.set(link, true, fly_to); 
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

#### Notes

- I can load kml on localhost
- can see kml code when accessing the link directly so file is there
- mime type is added
- This [kml url](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/download?mid=28b27372e2016cca82bddec656c63017&rtyp=k2) works on my page
- I also am having issues loading icons/placemarks which also don't appear in prod (symptom of something else?)
- could it be an api token issue?

Answer (score 0):

The kml in question was not publically accessible.  It was behind basic http auth.